# dijit.TitlePane with scroll?

Tags: dojo, javascript

Is there any way to have scroll bar in a dijit.TitlePane ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some problems with @BillKeese's answer.  However, all you need to do is set overflow to auto on the titlePane itself:

```
<div dojoType="dijit.TitlePane" style="width:100%; height:50%; overflow: auto">
    your content
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

TitlePane container div have `dijitTitlePaneContentInner` class, so you can use it in css style:

```html
<style>
    .dijitTitlePaneContentInner {
        overflow: auto;
        max-height: 30em;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to embed a DIV with a scrollbar:

```
<div dojoType=dijit.TitlePane ...>
      <div style="overflow: auto; height: 200px;>
          ...
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This didn't work in Firefox with Dojo 1.5. See my answer below.